# Using epsilon delta definition to prove that f is differentiable iff its component vectors are

Tags: multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

Question states:
"Show that a function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if all of its components $f_j: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ are differentiable for $1 \le j \le m$."

My instructor requires the use of epsilon delta proof for this problem. Although the concept in this problem is very intuitive, I couldn't really get a grip on this. I have been fiddling with the Jacobian matrix for couple hours, but I am really stuck. Any help would be great. I really want to learn how this can be proven rigorously.

Comment: this is a pretty standard proof. maybe you could start by spelling out your calculations. what exactly is the inequality you want to proof? do you already have some steps calculated?

Answer (score 1):

We can define the functions $\pi_j:\mathbb{R^m}\to\mathbb{R},\pi_j(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)=x_j$ and $g_j:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^m}, g_j(x)=(0,0,\ldots,x,\ldots,0)$ where the $x$ is at the $j$-th position. We can check that they are linear functions, hence differentiable. Now we see that $f_j=\pi_j\circ f$ and $\displaystyle f=\sum_{i=1}^m g_j\circ f_j$. Hence the statement follows.